# Wix Installer: Error 1925 when using silent installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6

In my wix setup, I use InstallScope="perMachine". In the interactive setup, there is no problem and it installs my application perfectly. However, when I try to install it from command line using /qn, I get the following error.

```
MSI (s) (60:EC) [11:51:05:268]: Product: ClickShare Launcher -- Error 1925. You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine. Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.
```

Could anyone tell me why it gives such problem only in silent installation? Does command line have different user privileges? 
Can I somehow detect if the user has required privileges and install the application perUser instead of perMachine? Would this be a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista,  MSI installs running from a standard user process requiring elevation cannot do so when running silent.  This is due to UAC.   Elevate the process prior to invoking msiexec.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set the install per user / per machine code as a parameter

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop>msiexec /i "program.msi"  MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1 ALLUSERS=2 /qn
```

this helped us on a application that did NOT require admin priviledge on interactive, but did require admin priviledge on silent mode....

maybe it helps some other users in the future... (from google searches)